# ontouchstart vs onmousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

i have a div with fixed width of 200px by 250px.  I can make the div content scroll nicely with javascript (on mousedown) up and down no problem in desktop browsers but i need to be able to get the div to scroll for my iphone/ipad (mobile touch screen divice).

how can i scroll a div with up and down linked controls for both desktop browsers and iphone/ipad (modile touch screens)

Is there some jquery that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery Mobile or Sencha.